# What's a NM thread?

Tags: linux, kernel, thread

I am studying OCFS2 kernel source code and I found this comment of function `dlm_lanuch_thread` in file *fs/ocfs2/dlm/dlmthread.c*:

> ```
> /* Launch the NM thread for the mounted volume */
> ```

So what does the "NM thread" mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the user's guide](http://oss.oracle.com/projects/ocfs2/dist/documentation/v1.2/ocfs2_users_guide.pdf), section 4, "O2CB Cluster Service":

> - NM: Node Manager that keep[sic] track of all the nodes in the cluster.conf